# Disable the loading of Stylesheets in UIWebView and/or WKWebView

Tags: swift, webview, uiwebview, webkit, wkwebview

I have absolutely tried everything with this one. I've read every apple article and no where can I find how to disable the loading of CSS (Styling) in the legacy UIWebView or the new WKWebView. I don't mind what web view I use just as long as it can accomplish this.

I've tried `WKPreferences()` and `WKWebViewConfiguration` and both have no member userStyleSheetEnabled.

I've referred myself to this apple article https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webpreferences/1536396-userstylesheetenabled?

Does anyone know the answer and how to achieve this on Swift 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebView` class you referenced is very old and has been deprecated. If you need to add a webview to your app, use `WKWebView` instead. This answer works with iOS >= 11 and macOS >= 10.13.

What you need is adding `WKContentRuleList` to your `WKWebView`'s configuration. They are similar to Safari content blockers (i.e. ad-blockers) that you may already have installed on your phone:

```
// This should ideally be in a file but we're using string for convenience
let jsonRuleList = """
[{
    "trigger": {
        "url-filter": ".*",
        "resource-type": ["style-sheet"]
    },
    "action": {
        "type": "block"
    }
}]
"""

// Compile the content-blocking list
WKContentRuleListStore.default().compileContentRuleList(forIdentifier: "blockStyleSheet", encodedContentRuleList: jsonRuleList) { list, error in
    guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
    guard let list = list else { return }

    // Add the stylesheet-blocker to your webview's configuration
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController.add(list)

    // Adding the webview to the view. Nothing to see here
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
    self.view.addSubview(self.webView)

    // Let's try Apple's website without CSS
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
    self.webView.load(request)
}
```

Result:

[image: Apple's website without stylesheet]

References

- [Customized Loading in WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/220/?time=2098) (WWDC video)
- [Creating Safari Content-Blocking Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Extensions/Conceptual/ContentBlockingRules/CreatingRules/CreatingRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016265-CH2-SW1)